# zfs pool creation: misaligned HDD?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, raid

I recently created a new ZFS pool, comming from btrfs. I followed the common and recent tutorials and checked with the man pages and the Ubuntu manual.

Every article says that ZFS will handle formatting and creating the partition table for me – and the results did look well.

I then did take a look into my dmesg log and found this suspicous line:

```
$ dmesg -H --color=always --follow --decode  --ctime
kern  :warn  : [Wed Dec  9 20:13:22 2020] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
```

Now I wonder how this could have happened. According to all manuals I found, this should not have happened. I would not care if this was not a warning. I also did not find much information about this error message.

Here is some info from hdparm:

```
(user@host)[~/] $ sudo hdparm -I  /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       WDC WD20EFRX-68EUZN0                    
        Serial Number:      WD-WCCXXXXXXXXP
        Firmware Revision:  82.00A82
        Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
        Supported: 9 8 7 6 5 
        Likely used: 9
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16383
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
        LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
        LBA48  user addressable sectors:  3907029168
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
        Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:     1907729 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:     2000398 MBytes (2000 GB)
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
        Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5400
```

Also:

```
$ zpool get all | grep ashift
nextcloud  ashift                         0                              default
```

So my thinking is:

- Remove one of both HDDs from the mirror
- create a new pool with manual ashift=12
- copy the data
- destroy the old pool
- attach the other HDD to the new pool

But maybe the transfer size has nothing to do with ashift? Help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

// Edit: System info

```
(user@host)[~] $ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

(user@host)[~] $ zfs --version
zfs-0.8.3-1ubuntu12.5
zfs-kmod-0.8.3-1ubuntu12.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not ZFS related, so I'll remove that tag from your question.

You may safely ignore this warning. The value for the "optimal transfer size" the HDD reports is obviously nonsense: `33553920` bytes are `65535` sectors (of `512` bytes). So the HDD reports `0xFFFF` sectors as optimal transfer size, which is a 16-bit-number with all bits set and usually means that the drive's firmware hasn't touched that value, or that it hasn't been programmed into the NV storage correctly (usual NAND flash has all bits set to 1 after erasing / initialization).

In older kernel versions, this could trick partitioning tools into misaligning partitions. Newer kernels have a sanity check and discard such weird values for the optimal transfer size, but output a warning to notify the user that his disk is telling nonsense.

`fdisk` usually complains if it encounters misaligned partitions, so if you do `fdisk -l` and don't see hints of that sort, you usually are on the safe side.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174404/hard-drive-partition-optimal-transfer-size) is an in-depth answer to the same question.

Comment: Great, thanks! Just a little bit confusing since it is a warning…